# not able to use title property in the document.getelementbyclass. error title property does not exist

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to assign some value where the class name is "grid-filter" but it's giving a compilation error in the angular typescript.

code

```
document.getElementByClassName('grid-filter')[0].title='new title';
```

Comment: Cast to HTMLElement

Comment: can u plz tell how to cast title property in type script.

Comment: (<HTMLElement>(document.getElementByClassName('grid-filter')[0])).title='new ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cast the element returned to an array of `HTMLElement` since you're selecting by class name:

```js
(document.getElementByClassName('grid-filter') as HTMLElement[])[0].title = 'new title';
```